# Access property in class from prototype override

Tags: javascript, class, prototype, prototype-programming

Not sure if my question is worded properly. But basically I have a class, but I want to write a new method for it. Say my class looks like this:

```js
class MyClass {
  constructor () {
    this.someProperty = []

    this.someMethod = this.someMethod.bind(this)
  }

  function someMethod () {
    // do something
  }
}
```

Now, because I don't have direct access to this class, I am going to create a new method using `prototype`

```js
MyClass.prototype.myNewMethod = function (params) {
  // do something else
  // how to access someProperty? And to the bind to MyClass?
}
```

But now say I want to access `someProperty` and also want to do the `bind` on this new method. How can I do that?

As a matter of fact is my method creation even correct to begin with? Anyway, what I want is for it to have the same access to the `this` inside the class. How can I do this?

Comment: All you need to do is call `myClassInstance.myNewMethod(args)` and it will work. But no, you cannot auto-bind this method without modifying the constructor.

Answer (score -1):

I didn't understand what you want to do but so you can access it:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor () {
    this.someProperty = [];

  }

  someMethod = function() {
    console.log(this.someProperty);
  }
}

var cc = new MyClass();
cc.someMethod();
```